# Opening Command and sending it commands with sendkey in visual basics

Tags: vb.net

This is the last part of my code and I am trying to open command prompt which works fine but as soon as as I put in code for the send keys command it goes crazy and opens 4 command prompts and does not execute the sendkeys in any of them. What I am trying to achieve is when I hit this button I want command prompt to open and automatically write these commands for me I think I need some kind of timer to slow it down but I do know know how to program the timer within the button any and all help would be appreciated. Here is my code

```
Private Sub btnExecute_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnExecute.Click
    Process.Start("cmd.exe")
    SendKeys.SendWait("cd c:\")
    SendKeys.SendWait("{ENTER}")
End Sub
```

Comment: You shouldn't be doing that at all.  What are you trying to do?

Comment: `SendKeys` is an unreliable method.

Comment: I Just want it to execute a batch file for auto install Kaspersky10 on my network pc's if I enter the commands myself by typing it works just fine, however I have other projects to work on and I want other network support guys to finish installing kaspersky on our remote machines and I dont want them to do anything but hit a few buttons and it works for them

Comment: why not just use Batch if it can install the program you can also set up choices using the choice command. it would save allot of time there is also a timeout command

Answer (score 0):

This is what I ended up doing and I got it to work

```
    Dim cd As String = "CD C:\"


    Process.Start("cmd.exe")


    Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000)
    SendKeys.SendWait(cd)
    Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000)
    SendKeys.SendWait("{ENTER}")
    Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000)
    SendKeys.SendWait("START KES1.bat")
    Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000)
    SendKeys.SendWait("{ENTER}")
```